# What is the industry standard Deduping method in Dataflows?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So Deduping is one of the basic and imp Datacleaning technique.

There are a number of ways to do that in dataflow.

Like myself doing deduping with help of aggregate transformation where i put key columns(Consider "Firstname" and "LastName" as cols) which are need to be unique in Group by and a column pattern like name != 'Firstname' && name!='LastName'
$$ _____first($$) in aggregate tab.

The problem with this method is ,if we have a total of 200 cols among 300 cols to be considered as Unique cols, Its a very tedious to do include 200 cols in my column Pattern.

Can anyone suggest a better and optimised Deduping process in Dataflow acc to the above situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to repro the deduplication process using dataflow. Below is the approach.

- List of columns that needs to be grouped by are given in dataflow parameters.
  In this repro, three columns are given. This can be extended as per requirements.

> ```
> Parameter Name: Par1
> Type: String
> Default value: 'col1,col2,col3'
> ```

[image]

- Source is taken as in below image.
  (Group By columns: col1, col2, col3;
  Aggregate column: col4)

[image]

- Then Aggregate transform is taken and in **group by**,
  `sha2(256,byNames(split($Par1,',')))` is given in columns and it is named as `groupbycolumn`
  [image]
- In Aggregates, **+ Add column pattern** near column1 and then delete Column1. Then Enter **true()** in matching condition. Then click on undefined column expression and enter `$$` in **column name expression** and `first($$)` in **value expression**.
  [image: gif31]

**Output of aggregation function**

[image]

Data is grouped by col1,col2 and col3 and first value of col4 is taken for every col1,col2 and col3 combination.

- Then using select transformation, **groupbycolumn** from above output can be removed before copying to sink.

Reference:  ** MS document** on [Mapping data flow script - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#distinct-row-using-all-columns)

Comment: So any way we need to add manual column names in the parameter.Can we get those dynamically filled in the parameter ???

Comment: Do you want to group by all columns? or group by only few columns out of total columns?

Comment: 1) If you want to take only few columns for group by columns, then yes, you need to manually add columns in the parameters and then pass it to Group by columns.
2) If you want to group by all columns, then in group by settings, enter this `sha2(256,columns())`